# Python - cgi field storage error

Tags: python, post, cgi

I have this in my python script

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print form
print form.getvalue("param")
```

the 2nd line prints `FieldStorage(None, None, 'param=abcd')` and the 3rd line causes an error

```
    File "/var/www/cgi-bin/use_save.py", line 24, in &lt;module&gt;
    print form.getvalue("param")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/cgi.py", line 548, in getvalue
    if key in self:
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/cgi.py", line 594, in __contains__
    raise TypeError, "not indexable"
    TypeError: not indexable
```

What is causing this error the value being passed just a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `enctype` of your form to either `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

More information here: http://www.futurequest.net/forums/showthread.php?t=14245

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp